# How can I write a conditional string_agg function in BigQuery?

Tags: google-bigquery, string-aggregation

I've written a query that looks at user journeys through my site, using the `string_agg()` function and `hits.contentGroup.contentGroup1` to group together product pages, advice pages, news pages and so on in sequential order, ordering them using the hit number and only looking at `'PAGE'` hit types.

However, sign up pages aren't grouped in the same way, so this results in `'(not set)'` values appearing throughout the user journey in the query's output table, if the user has sign up for an account.

Is there a way to apply conditions to the string_agg function, so that if the content group is `'not set'`, it can look at the corresponding page path, and if the page path matches `LIKE '%join/complete%'` for example, return `'Join Complete'` or a result other than `'not set'`?

This is my best attempt, but it only returns the results that contain join/complete, and not the rest of the user journey.

```sql
    SELECT
      date,
      fullVisitorId,
      visitId,
      STRING_AGG(
      CASE 
        WHEN hit.contentGroup.contentGroup1 = '(not set)' THEN 
        CASE 
          WHEN hit.page.pagePath LIKE '%join/complete%' THEN 'join_complete' 
          ELSE hit.contentGroup.contentGroup1 
        END 
      END
      , '#' ORDER BY hit.hitNumber)
    FROM `xxxxx-ga-datasets.xxxx.ga_sessions_*` AS t, 
    UNNEST(hits) AS hit
    WHERE
      _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN '20190101' AND '20190101'
      AND hit.type='PAGE'
    GROUP BY 1, 2, 3
    ORDER BY 1, 2
```

Any advice appreciated! Cheers.

Comment: For the users who are not familiar with GA data, could you please share some example rows of the table and the output you expect? Consider hiding or masking sensitive information.

Comment: Feel free to rephrase your question with sample rows like here https://gist.github.com/fpopic/7fdd0ae6949a94bbc131ba518cb23cd3 and please better explain the condition 'or a result other than 'not set'?` what do you want exactly to be written then?

Comment: Hi @fpopic - not sure what you mean by rephrasing the question with sample rows, I'm fairly new to SQL and very new to Stack Overflow so apologies! I've put together an anonymised version of the query, with the user journey showing the actual URLs, and also the content groupings, both ordered by hit number - https://i.imgur.com/3v1BMya.jpg What I would like to be able to do is apply some conditionality, so that when an uncategorised URL appears in the user journey, in this case the join/sign up pages, look at the URL and categorise it in the query itself. Hope that makes sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because your case-when construct returns `NULL` if the content group is not `not set`. You can simplify it to

```sql
    SELECT
      date,
      fullVisitorId,
      visitId,
      STRING_AGG(
      CASE 
        WHEN hit.page.pagePath LIKE '%join/complete%' THEN 'join_complete' 
        ELSE hit.contentGroup.contentGroup1  
      END
      , '#' ORDER BY hit.hitNumber)
    FROM `xxxxx-ga-datasets.xxxx.ga_sessions_*` AS t, 
    UNNEST(hits) AS hit
    WHERE
      _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN '20190101' AND '20190101'
      AND hit.type='PAGE'
    GROUP BY 1, 2, 3
    ORDER BY 1, 2
```

Comment: That is exactly what I was trying to do, works perfectly. Thank you!